# Theory behind state normalization in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: dynamic-programming, normalization, reinforcement-learning, batch-normalization

I know that normalizing the observation state returns better results in reinforcement learning [Stable-baselines documentation](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rl_tips.html).
But I could not find any theoretical background to back this theory up. I applied RL to robotics grasping. I receive the raw depth sensor values and input it into a series of convolutional layers, at the end receiving the 512-dimensional output. Without normalizing this output, the agent does not learn a working policy. But by applying normalization, it somehow achieves far better performance. I am not looking for a full mathematical proof. Instead, a logical explanation is enough.

Comment: [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask theoretical questions related to reinforcement learning, so I suggest that you ask your question there. If you ask it there, please, delete it from here (to avoid cross-posting, which is generally discouraged).